# Newsstand Kit Background download

Tags: iphone, ios, newsstand-kit

I have a Newsstand Application which uses Apple Newsstand Kit to download the contents.

When I start downloading a asset, it start perfectly downloads normally & all things gone fine. But if I start downloading & than quit the application & after that I have turnoff the wifi, Then restart the application & the downloading assets reconnected even the internet is not available. Now again I quit the application & turn on the wifi & launch the application.
The downloading Asset of NKLibrary has gone and I got nothing in the NKLibrary downloadingAsset.

```
NKLibrary *library = [NKLibrary sharedLibrary];

for(NKAssetDownload *asset in [library downloadingAssets]){
  [asset downloadWithDelegate:[NKDownloadManager defaultManager]];

  NSLog(@"reconnected");
}
```

I located the problem, it is due to the method `connectionDidFail:withError:`. if there is no internet then this method is called & the connection is terminated. Is there anyway to pause the connection or reconnect after termination.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't pause/reconnect with NSURLConnection. My suggestion is to check whether Wifi is available and then call "downloadWithDelegate", that way your NKAssetDownload won't be wasted

Comment: Thanks for reply Jack, but i have tried that, it does not work.